# Can't convert dump HPROF file from Android Studio to MAT format

Tags: android, hprof

When I try to convert HPROF file in android studio terminal  to MAT format:

1) hprof-conv [-z] d:/dump.hprof d:/outfile.hprof

2) hprof-conv d:/dump.hprof d:/outfile.hprof

I have the same  answer:

> Usage: hprof-conf [-z] infile outfile
>
> -z: exclude non-app heaps, such as Zygote
>
> Specify '-' for either or both files to use stdin/stdout.
>
> Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
>
> This software is built from source code licensed under the Apache License,
>   Version 2.0 (the "License"). You may obtain a copy of the License at
>
> ```
> http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
> ```
>
> See the associated NOTICE file for this software for further details.

But hprof-conf command is not present in android platform tools.

What shall I do to convert file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this problem, it has something to do with permissions I think.

It can be fixed by copying the input .hprof file into the "platform-tools/ " directory and specifying the output file to be somewhere with no permissions.

eg.

> hprof-conv in.hprof C:/Users/whatever_name/Desktop/out.hprof

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck on this for quite some time too. It seems you found hprof-conv.exe already and are running it as you should. What worked for me was putting the file into the location so in the 'platform-tools/' and then running it like this:

> hprof-conv myinputdump.hprof myoutputdump.hprof

I was getting your response when I wrote it like this:

hprof-conv ~/in.hprof ~/out.hprof

and putting -z anywhere in the command didn't get my anywhere.

So, just use the hprof-conv and then the file name then the output file name. I know putting the path characters like '~/' and your 'D:/' shouldn't matter, but excluding them worked for me and it might work for you.

Comment: I wrote like hprof-conv ~/in.hprof ~/out.hprof and then try hprof-conv in.hprof out.hprof. Don't work. Write the  same answer about the license. May be I should download the license but where and how?